# nginx: [emerg] open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, dockerfile, kubernetes-helm

I have the following Dockerfile that i have set up to use a new user rather than using root for my nginx server. The nginx server is built upon Redhat UBI image.
The image builds fine, however when I run the container I get the following error: nginx: [nginx: [emerg] open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)

Below is my dockerfile.

```
USER root
RUN microdnf --setopt=tsflags=nodocs install -y nginx procps shadow-utils net-tools ca-certificates dirmngr gnupg wget vim\
            && microdnf clean all \
            && rpm -q procps-ng

ENV NGINX_USER="api-gatway" \
    NGINXR_UID="8987" \
    NGINX_GROUP="api-gatway" \
    NGINX_GID="8987"     

RUN set -ex; \
  groupadd -r --gid "$NGINX_GID" "$NGINX_GROUP"; \
  useradd -r --uid "$NGINXR_UID" --gid "$NGINX_GID" "$NGINX_USER" 


COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

RUN mkdir -p /var/lib/nginx/tmp /var/log/nginx \
    && chown -R api-gatway:api-gatway /var/lib/nginx /var/log/nginx \
    && chmod -R 755 /var/lib/nginx /var/log/nginx

EXPOSE 1080
USER api-gatway
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

When i build the image, it builds without any errors, but when i deploy on my K8 cluster using helm, it gives me the following errors.

```
nginx: [emerg] open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

Here is my nginx.conf file that I have set up

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /tmp/error.log;
pid        /run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
  server {
    listen 1080;
    server_name localhost 127.0.0.1;
    access_log  /tmp/access.log;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    set  $allowOriginSite *;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
    # External settings, do not remove

    #ENV_ACCESS_LOG
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_set_header Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    location /search/ {
               proxy_pass http://*******-svc:8983/***/;
    }
    location /auth/ {
      proxy_pass http://********:8080;
    }
    location /mapbox {
      rewrite ^/mapbox(.*)https://****$1 break;
    }
  }
}
```

How can I fix nginx: [emerg] open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied) and what have i done wrong in my configurations?

Answer (score 13):

UPDATE

In order to fix my "/var/run/nginx.pid" permission denied error.

I had to add nginx.pid permission errors inside my dockerfile for the new user to work.

Below are the changes i made in my dockerfile

```
RUN touch /run/nginx.pid \
 && chown -R api-gatway:api-gatway /run/nginx.pid /cache/nginx
```

Comment: chown: cannot access '/cache/nginx': No such file or directory